# IntelliJ Plugin using Gradle gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

I'm trying a vanilla IntelliJ plugin which uses a shared module.

It seems the plugin build has found my `src` directory, but does not include the classes of my shared module. How do I tell gradle to include my shared library classes in the built plugin?

I tried adding a compile dependency, but no java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running in the IDE.

Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.12'
}

group 'com.prosc'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile files('out/production/MySharedLibrary')
}

intellij {
    version '2018.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Gradle. Use IntelliJ modules instead.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation for [org.jetbrains.intellij](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) hints for a `pluginName`:

```
intellij {
  version 'IC-2018.2.3'
  plugins = ['coverage', 'org.intellij.plugins.markdown:8.5.0.20160208']
  pluginName 'MySharedLibrary'
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` is similar:

```
val sdkVersion = System.getProperty("idea.version", "IC-2018.2.3")
val pluginName = "MySharedLibrary"

configure<IntelliJPluginExtension> {
    version = sdkVersion
    pluginName = pluginName
    setPlugins(
        "android",
        "CheckStyle-IDEA:5.3.1",
        "copyright",
        "CSS",
        "gradle",
        "Groovy",
        "JavaScriptLanguage",
        "junit",
        "properties",
        "uml"
    )
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but will need a little more explanation. Is this a .gradle file? Where are local paths referenced in here? The source files I need are not in a maven repository, they are on my local drive.

Comment: I followed your link to a different plugin .gradle file https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/blob/master/AngularJS/build.gradle and found the `sourceSets` declaration, which looks like it does what I need. Now I'm getting a build error because my shared library references `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller` but thanks for getting me going in the right direction.

Comment: @SamBarnum this is flagged as `internal` (not meant to be directly referenced), https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.0.1 might implement it.